# I just try to check what happens componentdidmount change state and value after render calls but get unexpected result

Tags: reactjs

Expected result is 20, but I get 10

[Image of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGOWT.png)

Comment: Don't post code **as image** - post the **actual code** as a **properly formatted text** here instead

Comment: setState is onestep behind,for seeing result use call back of set state,like this: this.setState({val: 20}, () => {console.log(''state -->",this.state.val)})

Comment: I tried but can't. I saw a video for properly formatted text and work like that but get  error@marc_s

Answer (score 0):

This is because `setState` is asynchronous. When you assign the value of state to res it's still 10.

You can use callback of setstate to asign value to res.

`this.setState({val: 20}, () => res - this.state.val)`

Or you can just asign the value inside render.

Answer (score 0):

Use `val` instead of `res` HTML in `render()` method. setState runs asynchronously, it will make update in few millisecond you can see that state variable renders *first 10 the after few milliseconds it will turn into 20*, because of asynchronous functionality.

Use like this,

```
render() {
  return (<h1>{val}</h1>);
}
```